# WSO2 IS - Invalid tenant domain when providing id_token_hint to logout endpoint

Tags: wso2, openid-connect, wso2-identity-server

I am evaluating WSO2 IS with a service provider that uses OpenID Connect (OIDC) for Inbound Authentication and a Federated Identity Provider (that also uses OIDC) for Outbound Authentication. The service provider is configured as a *SaaS Application*.

The login works fine so far. The logout should first call the logout endpoint at WSO2 IS and should then redirect to the identity provider's logout endpoint, by providing the `post_logout_redirect_uri` parameter with a respective value.

So when logging out at the service provider the following URL is called to logout at WSO2 IS:

```
https://wso2-is.local:9443/oidc/logout?post_logout_redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Ffed-idp.local%2Flogout&client_id=R0XGj...&id_token_hint=eyJ4NXQ...
```

This causes the following exception `Invalid tenant domain`:

```
[2017-10-16 14:41:16,327] ERROR {org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve} -  Servlet.service() for servlet [bridgeservlet] in context with path [/] threw exception
org.wso2.carbon.identity.base.IdentityRuntimeException: Invalid tenant domain mydomain.com
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.base.IdentityRuntimeException.error(IdentityRuntimeException.java:63)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.core.util.IdentityTenantUtil.getTenantId(IdentityTenantUtil.java:242)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.oidc.session.servlet.OIDCLogoutServlet.validateIdToken(OIDCLogoutServlet.java:226)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.oidc.session.servlet.OIDCLogoutServlet.processLogoutRequest(OIDCLogoutServlet.java:174)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.oidc.session.servlet.OIDCLogoutServlet.doGet(OIDCLogoutServlet.java:131)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:37)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:60)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.filter.CharacterSetFilter.doFilter(CharacterSetFilter.java:61)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:124)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:218)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:506)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.context.rewrite.valve.TenantContextRewriteValve.invoke(TenantContextRewriteValve.java:72)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.authz.valve.AuthorizationValve.invoke(AuthorizationValve.java:91)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.valve.AuthenticationValve.invoke(AuthenticationValve.java:60)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
        at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:57)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:159)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:962)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1115)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1770)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1729)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

The `mydomain.com` comes from the email address that is used to login at the federated identity provider and is the subject in the ID token. Using an email address with another domain shows in the error message accordingly.

For my usecase it is not feasible to add tenants in WSO2 IS for all possible email address domains.

Following are screenshots of the service and identity providers' configuration in WSO2 IS:

[Service provider config in WSO2 IS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PkIdL.png)

[Identity provider config in WSO2 IS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RVItJ.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set

`<EnableEmailUserName>true</EnableEmailUserName>`

in the server configuration (carbon.xml) as described here: https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Using+Email+Address+as+the+Username

Please note there are open TODOs in the WSO2 code: https://github.com/wso2-extensions/identity-inbound-auth-oauth/blob/4638700d60db7a0b9195e0cb8a09133b0797e718/components/org.wso2.carbon.identity.oidc.session/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/identity/oidc/session/servlet/OIDCLogoutServlet.java#L90

```
    /**
     * todo: At the moment we do not persist id_token issued for clients, thus we could not retrieve the RP that
     * todo: a specific id_token has been issued.
     * todo: Since we use a browser cookie to track the session, for the moment, we
     * todo: will validate if the logout request is being initiated by an active session via the cookie
     * todo: This need to be fixed such that we do not rely on the cookie and the request is validated against
     * todo: the id_token_hint received
     *
     * todo: Should provide a way to register post_logout_redirect_uris at IdP and should validate the received
     * todo: parameter against the set of registered values. This depends on retrieving client for the received
     * todo: id_token_hint value
     */
```